# Running a GUI written in R via script

Tags: r, user-interface, interactive

I wrote a small graphical user interface using the tcltk package in R. I now want to enable a user to start the interface by running a script without having to use RStudio or the commandline, but just by double clicking the script icon (in Windows). However I got some problems with doing that.

Running it with Rscript.exe starts a non-interactive R-session and I guess I need an interactive session. So I tried:

```
echo source("GUI.R") | R.exe --ess --vanilla
```

The R command interactive() in the GUI.R file now indeed returns TRUE, however the GUI window still only pops up and closes immediately afterwards.
Pausing the script after that does not help.

Does anyone know how to do it properly? Or if it is possible at all?

Comment: Why not run a batch file which is double clickable on Windows desktop?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, but the window closes immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old message but I am compelled to reply. I have been looking for solutions for similar problems for quite some time, none of them worked whatsoever. The problem is that RScript.exe, Rcmd.exe, etc. are not interactive and there is nothing you can do about it.

I solved the problem using tkwait.window() in the very end of the file (I am using tlctk2) that I am running with Rscript.exe.

Make sure there are no if(interactive()) routines, as Rscript.exe is not interactive and will, therefore, return FALSE to interactive().

The result is simple and effective. The window that you created using tcl/tk GUI will stay up and running until it is destroyed with tkdestroy() or just by closing the window.

```
#usage
require(tcltk2)
#Your script
MyMainWindow<<-tktoplevel()
#Your script
tkwait.window(MyMainWindow)
#END
```