# Runing an R Script that includes messageboxes from the windows terminal

Tags: r, windows, automation

I am trying to run a simple R Script that creates a messagebox using the R library svDialogs:

```
library(svDialogs)
user.input <- dlgInput("Enter a number", Sys.info()["user"])$res
```

This runs well whe I execute it using RStudio for example:

```
RStudio 2922.02.1 Build 461, using 
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes" 
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

However, I have also tried to run this using a .bat file:

```
"Path_to_Rscript\Rscript.exe" Path_to_File\File.r
```

I have used .bat files to automate the sequential execution of RScripts from different R installations and Architectures (32Bit and 64bit), but I am having problems executing RScripts that require showing these messageboxes to either show data or to require input from users.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a solution using tcltk here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211294/running-a-gui-written-in-r-via-script